# Issue with Alamofire + AFNetworking at the same time

Tags: ios, afnetworking, alamofire

I'm working on a project using both Objective C and Swift 3. We use both Alamofire and AFNetworking for network request.

Dev Environment :

> 'AFNetworking', '3.1.0'
>   'Alamofire', '4.4.0'

My issue is: When a request (request 1) make with Alamofire is in progress (uploading file), i excute an another request with AFNetworking (request 2). Request 2 not excute immediately until request 1 finish. When request 1 finish request 2 will trigger automatically

Can anyone give me some idea on this issue?

P/S: I'm not using the same `URLSession`.

Swift: I'm using background configuration.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier)

// Using background session instead of default URLSession

let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Obj C: i'm using default session

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
```

Comment: try with request using DispatchSemaphore or NSOperationQueue using either Alamofire or AFNetworking instead of using both